# React Localhost Proxy Working in Dev but not with Serve

Tags: reactjs, proxy, localhost

I'm having a strange issue when trying to use a Proxy for Localhost in a React App (created with create-react-app). The backend server is running on

```
localhost:3000
```

The Proxy is setup in as many places as I could put it

/src/.env

```
DANGEROUSLY_DISABLE_HOST_CHECK=true
REACT_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:3000
```

/package.json

```
{
  ...
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3000",
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "PORT=4000 WDS_SOCKET_PORT=0 react-scripts start",
    "serve": "serve -s -p 4000 ./build > logfile.log 2>&1 &"
  }
  ...
}
```

/src/setupProxy.tsx

```
import { createProxyMiddleware } from "http-proxy-middleware";

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(
        "/api",
        createProxyMiddleware({
            target: "http://localhost:3000",
            changeOrigin: true,
        })
    );
};
```

Then doing the fetch call as

```
fetch(this.url, config)
    .then((res:any) => { return res.json(); })
    .then((res:any) => { resolve(res); })
    .catch((err:any) => {
        console.log(err);
        reject("Broken Fetch");
    });
```

And when running with `npm run start` (with react-scripts) then everything is working correctly but when running with `npm run serve` (with serve) the fetch calls fail and don't seem to be using the proxy at all with an error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!doctype "... is not valid JSON
```

Comment: Your serve is set to port `4000` while your `target: "http://localhost:3000",` is looking at port `3000`.  It seems that you need to have a "switch" that looks at whatever port you are indenting ..  Dev, or Production.  You should be able to set these up as variables in your setup as to detect what you are running and use accordingly ..  Something like `target: "http://localhost:" + {portNumber},` and you can set `portNumber` based on logic that detects whether you're running dev or production.

Comment: The Port 4000 is for the React frontend and Port 3000 is for the backend server